# creating filtered index on complex views oracle 12c R1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to Create a Filtered Index on a Complex view to make queries fast
but i am facing problem while creating index

Below is Simple Syntax i am trying to create index

`CREATE INDEX XX_RGU_INV ON XX_AR_INV (TRANS_TYPE = 'Regular Invoice')`

When i try to Create index it give me error

`ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

I have complex view `XX_AR_INV` on which i have to filter data many times on different criteria for on only TRANS_TYPE = 'Regular Invoice'

Comment: Thanks Sami.  One cannot create an index on a view.  The underlying table(s) that carries `TRANS_TYPE` will need to be targeted for indexing instead, or the view will need to be materialized to allow for indexing.

Comment: TRANS_TYPE is in Join Condition so you mean we have to create index on actual table which hold `Regular Invoice` value even it is join  ?
So this is will make query more fast right ?

Comment: So what will be the Syntax if i create on the table for only `Regular Invoices`

Comment: Created Index `CREATE INDEX XX_RGU_INV ON ra_cust_trx_types_all (CASE WHEN NAME = 'Regular Invoice' THEN NAME END)` but it doesn't impact on query time

Comment: Thanks Sami.  If indexing `TRANS_TYPE` has no impact on the query, then it may not be the source of the performance problem (though I would recommend starting with a typical index rather than a conditional).  Have you identified `ra_cust_trx_types_all` as the source of the problem, and checked the accuracy of the stats in the plan, etc.?  If you are uncertain of the root problem, updating the question to include the explain plan for the view's query would be helpful.  Thanks

Comment: @Sami if you mean the index is not being used by your query then are you using the exact index expression in the query? If your function-based index is on a `case` expression then your query has to refer either to that same expression or an equivalent virtual column. However it all seems like overkill for your `trans_type` column. How many types are there anyway?